# How do you change the values in a dimension a different color, but keep the others the color they have?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a field called ABC Code and I have A,B,C,D, I & Z.

I just want to make the contents in I and Z to be black.  For the other letters, I have coloring for the contents based on different criteria.

Comment: See [ask]. Provide your [mcve] and show your research.

Answer (score 0):

Drop ABC Code on the color card, then double click in the color legend.  From there you can manually assign your colors.

Comment: I tried this, but it looks like it overwrites what I have already for A,B, C & D. Those items have a %. High % then green, then orange and then red.  If you think of anything else, please let me know. I also tried clicking on it and go to format, but that doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Fact check me here;  You have a dimension (not measure) called 'ABC Code'.  The values in this field are A,B,C,D,I & Z.  Your requirements are;  Color I & Z Black...color others based on other business rules.  If this is correct, what are the other rules?

Comment: I got an answer to this. Its using attr(ABC Code) = "I" and attr(Abc code) = "Z" then "black"  Elseif ...then the rest of the code for the variance field.